# How do I fix an as.date error with origin?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a code to calculate time series for when companies will merge. I keep getting the error:
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing
`X1 = as.Date(X1)`.
Caused by error in `as.Date.numeric()`:
! 'origin' must be supplied
Backtrace:

1. df %>% ...
2. base::as.Date.numeric(X1)
3. base::stop("'origin' must be supplied")

I have tried several different things but cannot figure out what is wrong. Here is my code:

```
 tech[which.max(tech$time),]
merge_freq%>%
  ggplot(aes(prop_in_year, reorder(`Parent.Company`,prop_in_year,median)))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='lightgreen')+
  labs(title='Merging Proporbility in every month in one year',
       x='Proporbility',
       y='Company')+
  theme_bw()
set.seed(100)

nxt_merge<-function(prop){
  if(prop<1){
    draw<-c(rep(1,prop*1000), rep(0,(1-prop)*1000))
    if (draw[sample(1000,1)] == 1)
      return (T)
    else
      return (F)
  }
  else
    return(T)
}

prop_nxt<-tech%>%
  group_by(`Parent.Company`)%>%
  summarise(time = time[which.max(time)])%>%
  mutate(prop_mth = merge_freq$prop_in_year)

df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 14))
for( i in 1:10){
  df[i]<-unlist(lapply( prop_nxt$prop_mth, nxt_merge))
}

df<-prop_nxt[,-3]%>%cbind(df)

for( i in 1:14){
  for( j in 3:12){
    if(df[i,j] == T)
      df[i,j] = AddMonths(df[i,j-1],1)
    else
      df[i,j] = df[i,j-1]
  }
}


df<-tibble(df)
df<-df%>%
  mutate( X1 = as.Date(X1), 
          X2 = as.Date(X2),
          X3 = as.Date(X3),
          X4 = as.Date(X4),
          X5 = as.Date(X5),
          X6 = as.Date(X6),
          X7 = as.Date(X7),
          X8 = as.Date(X8),
          X9 = as.Date(X9),
          X10 = as.Date(X10))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell just from your code, but what's probably happening is that these lines in your code

```
if(df[i,j] == T)
      df[i,j] = AddMonths(df[i,j-1],1)
else
      df[i,j] = df[i,j-1]
```

are producing results that are numbers, not dates. Probably that `else` condition specifically. And when you try to coerce a number to a date, you cannot do it with base R's `as.Date()` without supplying a reference point--i.e. an origin value, which is what the error message/backtrace is asking for. `as.Date()` interprets a number as meaning "some number of days  since a starting date". As the help for `as.Date()` says,

```
## S3 method for class 'character'
as.Date(x, format, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"),
        optional = FALSE, ...)
## S3 method for class 'numeric'
as.Date(x, origin, ...)
## S3 method for class 'POSIXct'
as.Date(x, tz = "UTC", ...)

[...] The as.Date methods accept character strings, factors, 
logical NA and objects of classes "POSIXlt" and "POSIXct". 

[...] as.Date  will accept numeric data (the number of 
days since an epoch), but only if origin is supplied.
```

You will either need to pick a reference point for the n days elapsed or ensure that the contents of `df` are in a form (e.g. a date string) that can be turned into a Date. If you're working with tidyverse stuff already, you may find that one or other of the functions in its `lubridate` package will do what you want more easily.